# How to select from one table and a sub table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have something like the following two tables in SQL Server:

```
Table1
MainID Descrip
     1 tree
     2 dog
     3 blah
     4 etc

Table2
SubID MainID SubDescrip
    1      2 rover
    2      2 fido
```

I want to be able to select all from Table1 and Table2 when it has a matching MainID.

My desired output is as follows:

```
MainID Descrip SubID SubDescrip
     1 tree     NULL       NULL
     2 dog      NULL       NULL
     2 dog         1      rover
     2 dog         2       fido
     3 blah     NULL       NULL
     4 etc      NULL       NULL
```

I can get all but the second row of the desired output with an outer join, but how do I get that second row as well?

In other words, this:

```
SELECT m.MainID, m.Descrip, s.SubID, s.SubDescrip
FROM Table1 m LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Table2 s ON m.MainID = s.MainID
ORDER BY m.MainID, s.SubID
```

gives me this:

```
MainID Descrip SubID SubDescrip
     1 tree     NULL       NULL
     2 dog         1      rover
     2 dog         2       fido
     3 blah     NULL       NULL
     4 etc      NULL       NULL
```

but I want this as well:

```
 2 dog      NULL       NULL
```

Comment: that looks like expected output to me. you would only get the null values on row 2 in your "desired output" if the MainID didn't exist in table 2, but it does. That aside, what's the reason for wanting this extra row? I'm struggling to think of any case where it would be useful.

Comment: Yes I know, so how would I get my desired output

Comment: I think this is not possible. You can achieve this with PL/SQL but not with queries.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to use T-SQL, but if that's what I need to do then that's what I'll have to do

Comment: Look into using a UNION query if you really need this output. Seems like a bad bad design decision has been made somewhere if you need output like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `UNION`

```
SELECT  m.MainID, 
        m.Descrip, 
        s.SubID, 
        s.SubDescrip
FROM    Table1 m 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 s 
            ON m.MainID = s.MainID
UNION
SELECT  MainID, 
        Descrip, 
        NULL SubID, 
        NULL SubDescrip
FROM    Table1
ORDER   BY MainID, SubID
```

Comment: This works and is faster than rsocol's solution although, speed is not a factor with the small amount of data I will be dealing with

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
    SELECT m.MainID, m.Descrip, s.SubID, s.SubDescrip
    FROM Table1 m INNER JOIN
         Table2 s ON m.MainID = s.MainID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m.MainID, m.Descrip, NULL, NULL
    FROM Table1 m
    ORDER BY MainID, SubID
```

Razvan

Comment: This doesn't work - incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'